# I have a results page in React, and I would like to link each result to a detail page but with dynamic URLs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, router

I have a results page in React, all values are fetched from an external url through API and then rendered. 
Now, I would like to link each item result to its detail page, which as I understand, could be rendered by a unique page template or component (detailTemplate.js), but URL must be different for each result. It 's dynamically calculated as is one of the item attributes.

results.js

```
 ....
 <ul>
 {data.map((item) => (
    <li>
     <Link to={item.url}>
         <div>item.name </div>
         <div>item.price</div>
     </Link>
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
...
```

---

detailTemplate.js

```
export const DetailPage= (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>
                {props.item.title}
            </h3>
            <div>
                {props.item.description}
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
```

---

How can I link from results.js to DetailPage, for all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `Declarative Routing` in react. You can do it easily with the `<Route />` component like this. In your `App.js` file, you can define your path and a `slug`, which you can access later in the component you navigate to.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Results} />
        <Route path="/detail/:slug" component={Details} />
       </Switch>
     </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can specify the path in your  component like this:

```
//results.js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/detail/${url}`,
    price:item.price,
    name:item.name
  }}
>
  <div>item.name </div>
  <div>item.price</div>
</Link>;
```

And in your `detailTemplate.js` you can access the props like this.

```
export const DetailPage = ({ location }) => {
  console.log(location);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{location.price}</h3>
      <div>{location.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Results path works fine, but Detail nope. I don't reach to the detail page, and  I have coded exactly what you posted. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello @larrytron, I have made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-violet-djh4t?file=/src/Results.js) for this just now. Do check it out.